# Handle webhook event in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, get, webhooks

Here I have an asp.net webappliccation.in this  we have a payment method. Here when the user completes the payment , the bank merchant portal  will send a webhook response to our site eg(:[www.mysite.com/home.aspx](http://www.mysite.com/home.aspx)) .
I have an issue with getting the response using webhook handler. here is my code..

**Aspx.cs code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EmailID = "akhilqaz@gmail.com";
    string SMSContent = "";
    string Messages = "";
    string Sender = "";

    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string data = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd().ToString().Trim();
            var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
             MResponse obj1 = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<MResponse>(data);
             SMSContent = obj1.ToString();
             if (obj1 != null)
             {
                 SMSContent = obj1.ToString();

                 SendOrderDetailsByMail(EmailID, SMSContent, Messages, Sender, UserId);
             }           
        }
    }
    catch //(Exception ex)
    {
        //Log exception
    }
   Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

Note:here I would like to send the Webhook response to the particular email id
if anyone  please help it would be great help..

this is my request body

```
{"localId":null,"customerReference":null,"transactionId":"5fb74e08975e8a00087fbd92","state":"QR_CODE_GENERATED","created":"2020-11-20T05:03:41.222Z","signature":"fENP+McwMbbbTya+YJFUaQ==","amount":100,"currency":"MVR","securityWord":"","provider":"bml_epos","qrCode":{"url":"https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bankofmaldives-qr-codes-raeto7je-uat/5f094c0ebbf16d0007df8148/transactions/5fb74e08975e8a00087fbd92_ilc1z71605848619.png"},"orderInfo":null}
```

Comment: What are you getting in the request. Rather than using stream you can simple use `Requst["key"]` or "Request.Forms["key"]" or `Request.QueryString.Get' . If you are getting some error post that as well. Also how they are posting data using get or post?

Comment: @शेखर  update in requested body the question please

Comment: Can you put code for sending mail? Do you have details for sending Emails like SMTP or any other protocol using which you want to send mail? Normally you create a HTML with data and then send it over the mail.

Comment: @शेखर the e mail is already working fine...

Comment: So what do you want? Send to a particular email? Set it in to.